# Safari won't let me full screen a popup with overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, css, safari

Currently trying to have a full screen popup in safari when the user has a small screen (e.g. Iphone 5). In chrome this works as expected but cant seem to figure out how to make this work on safari.

The idea is that the popup should take up the whole screen of the device and should only scroll with the content of the popup (so not the entire html document).

[See the jsbin for full code.](https://jsbin.com/nojihoyize/edit?css,js,output)

As mentioned this works on chrome, not on safari for some reason...

I've scanned multiple articles and found that you need to apply the following to both body and html. This however doesn't solve the issue.

```
.no-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the markup that shows the problem here, not a fiddle which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one: [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I have also encountered this problem, And I found two ways to solve this err in the Google.

=============================================

the First Way:

edit css:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

but this way in my environment did not work.

the Second Way:

edit css:

```
body {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

but this way will upset the layout.

============================================

I started to trying other ways, and I found a solution with my team finally.

edit css:

```
body {
  overflow: initial;
}
hidden-div {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll try it as soon as I can!

Comment: I've tried this but did not work for us. Just to verify with `hidden-div` you mean the popup?